# How to check if expression contains a Complex expression?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

Is there a way to check if an expression contains complex expressions / imaginary numbers?

The documentation says that you can't check if an expression contains `I` because of how it is interpreted.
I have also tried `ImaginaryQ[expr_] := expr != Conjugate[expr]` and `Simplify[expr] =!= Simplify[Conjugate[expr]]`, but it does not yield accurate results.
I have also tried to use MemberQ[expr, Complex], but that does not seem to work either.

I posted some examples into a notebook:
http://www.eacousineau.com/download/complex-test.nb

Comment: Do you need to check for expressions like `(-1)^(1/3)` or just explicit `Complex[a, b] == a + I b` objects which Yoda's answer addresses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
ImaginaryQ[expr_] := ! FreeQ[expr, _Complex]
```

Using it on two of your examples:

```
imExpr = a Sin[a + 2 I];
ImaginaryQ@imExpr
(* True *)

reExpr = a Sin[a^2 + a];
ImaginaryQ@reExpr
(* False *)
```

Comment: That works perfectly! But why is the form argument for FreeQ a pattern, _Complex, instead of just a symbol, Complex?

Comment: `Complex` is the head for all complex numbers & expressions. So we use a pattern `_Complex` to capture anything with that `Head`. If you used the symbol `Complex` instead, this example: `FreeQ[{a,b,Complex},Complex]` will return `False`, eventhough `Complex` is **not** a complex number... `FreeQ[{a,b,Complex},_Complex]` returns `True` as it should.

Answer (score 3):

To be clear as to why `MemberQ[expr,Complex]` will not necessarily return `True` for reals (and may or may not return `True` for complex expressions). `MemberQ` is not asking if something is a member of the set of reals or anything like that.

`MemberQ[expr,form]` returns `True` if one of the elements of level 1 of `expr` matches `form`. Level 1 is what you get second from top if you do `TreeForm`. Also, by default, `MemberQ` does not look at heads. Thus:

```
l = List[1 + I];
MemberQ[l, Complex, Heads -> True]
MemberQ[List@l, Complex, Heads -> True]
(*
-> 
True
False
*)
```

(the `Heads->True` part is to make `MemberQ` also look at heads of expressions). To understand why, look at `TreeForm@l` and `Treeform[List@l]`:

[image]

Thus, there is a `Complex` at the first level in the first case, and no `Complex` at level 1 in the second. This is why we get `True` and `False` above. One can use

```
MemberQ[List@l, Complex, -1, Heads -> True]
(*
-> True
*)
```

to match on all levels.

Finally, to see that `MemberQ` really is a structural question, try `MemberQ[1 + Exp[3*I], Complex, Heads -> True]` which gives `False` even though the first argument is obviously complex.

So to sum up, `MemberQ` has little to do with mathematics; it's a construct to test patterns in lists (or any expression, the head does not matter).

In any case, if one is going to use structural tests, `FreeQ` is the [easiest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524107/how-to-check-if-expression-contains-a-complex-expression/6524497#6524497), while `Element` [is the way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524107/how-to-check-if-expression-contains-a-complex-expression/6524145#6524145) with mathematical tests.

Comment: @yoda sure, I wouldn't use `Element` either as I think of it as an assertion rather than a test. I was commenting on the answer  stating that `MemberQ[expr, Complex]` should not be used because that should give `True` for real numbers, which I felt reflected a lack of distinction between structural and mathematical operations (ie, `MemberQ` is not about being or not being a member of a mathematical set)

Comment: @yoda: If Mathematica were smart enough, `Not[Element[a + b I, Reals]]` would return something like `b = 0`.  I would think `Element[a + I b, Complexes]` would return `True`.  (All this is assuming that we tell Math'ca that `a` and `b` are `Reals`.)

Comment: Yes of course. I meant to post that to the other answer. I've done that and removed this :)

Comment: @Charles Thanks! By the way, what you want is more what `Reduce` does than `Elements`; thus `Reduce[a + b*I \[Element] Reals, {a, b}]` or `Reduce[a + b*I \[Element] Reals && a \[Element] Reals && 
  b \[Element] Reals, {a, b}]`

Comment: @acl I agree with Charles - great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `MemberQ[expr, Complex]` because that should give `True` for real numbers. Or rather, `Element[expr, Complexes]` would—I'm not sure what, if anything, your version would do. What about

```
Not[Element[expr, Reals]]
```

or

```
Im[expr] != 0
```

?

Comment: `MemberQ[expr, Complex]` does not return `True` for reals because it is a structural question, not a mathematical one

Comment: @yoda: Thanks, corrected.  Mathematica is something like my 10th language and I get confused every so often.

Comment: @Charles: Yes, that's a mistake I make often too :) For me it's more common with `Real` because, `Real` is a valid head in Mathematica and the syntax coloring won't highlight it, whereas I catch `Imag` instantly because it's undefined and shows up as blue.

Comment: @yoda, @Charles and how about `Trace` vs `Tr`, especially with something along the lines of `f[i_] := i^2; Trace[Table[f[i], {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}]]` (page of stuff) vs `f[i_] := i^2; Tr[Table[f[i], {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}]]` (385)...

Comment: @Charles: Btw, the problem with `Element` is for undefined symbols, it's more of an assertion than a test. For e.g. `Element[a + I b, Complexes]`. Mathematically, yes it shouldn't return either `True` or `False`, because we haven't defined `a` and `b`. However, I assume OP wanted to only check for the presence of a `I` in the expression. Similarly, `Im[expr]` also doesn't always return true/false (e.g., check with OP's first example `imExpr`)

Comment: @yoda: I assume the opposite: that the OP would want `I^2` to return `False` and `Root[#^4+1&,1]` to return `True`.