# How to find if expression contains complex number I in it in SymPy?

Tags: sympy, complex-numbers

Given an expression, how do I find (after simplifications if needed) if the expression contains the complex number `I` which is the square root of −1?

In Maple, this is done using the check `has(expression,I)`; see its [help page](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=has).

In Mathematica, this is done using the check `If[FreeQ[expression, Complex]`, for example: [How to check if expression contains a Complex expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524107/how-to-check-if-expression-contains-a-complex-expression)

But I am not sure how to do similar thing in SymPy.

Using `expression.is_complex` does not return `True` even if `I` in the expression. Also since real is subset of complex, this is not a correct test anyway.

I need to check for an explicit `I` that shows up in the expression anywhere (after simplification).

Here is an example: I am using SymPy 1.5.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import z
ex1=(-(((1 + 3*I) + sqrt(2))*cos(z/2)) + ((1 + I) - I*sqrt(2))*sin(z/2))/(((1 + I) + sqrt(2))*cos(z/2) + I*((-1 -I) + sqrt(2))*sin(z/2))
print(ex1.is_complex)
    #None
print(simplify(ex1).is_complex)
    #None
```

This is in Maple, for reference:

```
restart;
result:=(-(((1 + 3*I) + sqrt(2))*cos(z/2)) + ((1 + I) - I*sqrt(2))*sin(z/2))/(((1 + I) + sqrt(2))*cos(z/2) + I*((-1 -I) + sqrt(2))*sin(z/2));
has(simplify(result),I)
```

Which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How to do the above in SymPy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`has` checks whether an expression contains some subexpression, such as `I`:

```
ex1.has(I)        # True
sin(z).has(I)     # False
(sin(z)+I).has(I) # True
```

Note that this does not take into account simplifications that might get rid of the `I`.

As for checks like `is_complex`, they consider all possible values of the input variable and return `None` if there is no clear answer (or if SymPy does not see a relevant simplification). Also, in your case, you want to use `is_real` (since real numbers are also complex in SymPy’s sense, as you noted). For illustration, consider the following:

```
z = Symbol("z")
(z+1).is_real  # None
(z+I).is_real  # None

z = Symbol("z", real=True)
(z+1).is_real  # True
(z+I).is_real  # False
```